# Changing boxplot in graphics to bwplot in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I have a problem changing `boxplot` in the `graphics` package to an equivalent in the `lattice` package.

graphics:

```
xx1 <- rnorm(20, mean = 3, sd = 3.6)
xx2 <- rpois(40, lambda = 3.5)
xx3 <- rchisq(31, df = 5, ncp = 0)
box1 <- boxplot(xx1, xx2, xx3, names = c("Group-1", "Group-2",
                                         "Group-3"), cex = 0.7)
```

How to use `lattice::bwplot`for box1?

after creating new variable `data<-c(xx1, xx2, xx3)` and placing it into `bwplot`, I receive only one plot instead of three (one for each distribution). Could you please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to do that using `lattice` package

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(xx1, levels ="Group-1")
df2 <- data.frame(xx2, levels ="Group-2")
df3 <- data.frame(xx3, levels ="Group-3")
colnames(df1) <- c("Data","Group")
colnames(df2) <- c("Data","Group")
colnames(df3) <- c("Data","Group")

df <- bind_rows(df1,df2,df3)#To bind dataframes with different number of rows

bwplot(Data~Group,df)
```

Comment: If it has worked for you, you can think of accepting it as answer to your question by clicking √.